# I am trying to get simple jquery code to iterate

Tags: jquery, sudoku

I am trying to assign text to a sudoku puzzle (made with a table) using jquery and can do it by indvidual cell using the following code:

```
$('#popSud').click(function(){
$('#1').text('1');
});
```

but I want to apply it to the entire 81 cell table and am trying the following code but no success:

```
function popSud(sudName) {
  for (var i = 0; i<81; i++) {
    $('#i').text(sudName[i-1]);
  }
}
$('#popSud').click(function(){
     popSud(easy);
  });
```

I managed to get all my errors to disappear using the dev tools so I am hitting a wall.  I am using an 81 number array for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part does not work:

```
 $('#i').text(sudName[i-1]);
```

jQuery is literally looking for the element with id "i", not with the number you are looking for.

Try this code:

```
 $('#' + i).text(sudName[i-1]);
```

Note that `i` starts counting with 0, so your element ids have to start with 0 as well. Looks like you will have a couple off-by-one errors in your code as it is now.

Besides that, I would recommend to reconsider your the names you give your functions and variables. Right now, you might know what `popSud` means, but if you have to touch the code again in 6 months? Probably not so much. Why don't you just call it `populateSudoku`? Considering the fact that pretty much all modern development environments have a code completion feature, the additional legibility comes completely free!

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was most helpful.  I will take said recommendation into consideration